# convert data from multiple columns into single row sorting descending

Tags: sql

I am trying to query the original source which contain totals from a category (in this case Vehicles) into the second table.

| Motorcycle | Bicycle | Car |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |

Desired Output:

| Vehicle | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Bicycle | 3 |
| Car | 2 |
| Motorcycle | 1 |

Additionally, I need that the Quantity is sorted in descending order like showing above.

So far I have tried to do an Unpivot, but there is a syntax error in the Unpivot function. Is there another way to reach out the same results?

My code so far:

```
SELECT Vehicle_Name 
FROM 
( 
SELECT [Motorcycle], [Bycycle], [Car] from Data
) as Source  
UNPIVOT 
( 
Vehicle FOR Vehicle_Name IN ([Motorcycle], [Bycycle], [Car])
) as Unpvt
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (UNPIVOT is a non-standard feature.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Added sort requirement.

You can use `CROSS APPLY` here too

```
select vehicle, amnt
from test
cross apply( 
 VALUES('motorcycle', motorcycle)
   ,('bicycle', bicycle)
   ,('car', car)) x (vehicle, amnt)
order by amnt desc
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64363f9e5c1943d12d252497a09fdfd2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
with data1 as 
(
Select * from data)
Select * From 
(
Select 'motorcycle' as "Vehicle", motorcycle  as quantity from data1  
union all 
Select 'bicycle' , bicycle from data1
union all 
Select 'car', car from data1
)  order by quantity desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Since we don't know what DBMS, here's a way that'd work in the one I use the most.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT map_from_entries(
                   ARRAY[('Motorcycle', Motorcycle),
                         ('Bicycle', Bicycle),
                         ('Car', Car)])
        FROM Source) AS t1(type_quant)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(type_quant) AS t2(Vehicle, Quantity)
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

-Trino